# Beautiful soup web page scraper

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a webpage with following url 
https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/shpSecurities.aspx?scripcd=500209&qtrid=96.00

and I want to scrape a table with following html code. I have tried few things but not able to achieve the desired table to insert into csv.Here the **<"tr">** tag is not closed for the data so segregating the data into different row is an issue.

Thanks for help
--J

```
<table border='0' width='900' align='center' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='4'>
                <tr>
                    <td class='innertable_header1' rowspan='3'>Category of shareholder</td>
                    <td class='innertable_header1' rowspan='3'>Nos. of shareholders</td>
                    <td class='innertable_header1' rowspan='3'>No. of fully paid up equity shares held</td>
                    <td class='innertable_header1' rowspan='3'>No. of shares underlying Depository Receipts</td>
                    <td class='innertable_header1' rowspan='3'>Total nos. shares held</td>
                    <td class='innertable_header1' rowspan='3'>Shareholding as a % of total no. of shares (calculated as per SCRR, 1957)As a % of (A+B+C2)</td>
                    <td class='innertable_header1' rowspan='3'> Number of equity shares held in dematerialized form</td>
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class='TTRow_left'>(A) Promoter & Promoter Group</td>
                    <td class='TTRow_right'>19</td>
                    <td class='TTRow_right'>28,17,02,889</td>
                    <td class='TTRow_right'></td>
                    <td class='TTRow_right'>28,17,02,889</td>
                    <td class='TTRow_right'>12.90</td>
                    <td class='TTRow_right'>28,17,02,889</td>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='TTRow_left'>(B) Public</td>
                        <td class='TTRow_right'>9,16,058</td>
                        <td class='TTRow_right'>1,87,81,45,362</td>
                        <td class='TTRow_right'>1,32,95,642</td>
                        <td class='TTRow_right'>1,89,14,41,004</td>
                        <td class='TTRow_right'>86.61</td>
                        <td class='TTRow_right'>1,88,74,40,959</td>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='TTRow_left'>(C1) Shares underlying DRs</td>
                            <td class='TTRow_right'></td>
                            <td class='TTRow_right'></td>
                            <td class='TTRow_right'></td>
                            <td class='TTRow_right'></td>
                            <td class='TTRow_right'>0.00</td>
                            <td class='TTRow_right'></td>
                            <tr>
                                <td class='TTRow_left'>(C2) Shares held by Employee Trust</td>
                                <td class='TTRow_right'>1</td>
                                <td class='TTRow_right'>1,08,05,896</td>
                                <td class='TTRow_right'></td>
                                <td class='TTRow_right'>1,08,05,896</td>
                                <td class='TTRow_right'>0.49</td>
                                <td class='TTRow_right'>1,08,05,896</td>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class='TTRow_left'>(C) Non Promoter-Non Public</td>
                                    <td class='TTRow_right'>1</td>
                                    <td class='TTRow_right'>1,08,05,896</td>
                                    <td class='TTRow_right'></td>
                                    <td class='TTRow_right'>1,08,05,896</td>
                                    <td class='TTRow_right'>0.49</td>
                                    <td class='TTRow_right'>1,08,05,896</td>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class='TTRow_left'>Grand Total</td>
                                        <td class='TTRow_right'>9,16,078</td>
                                        <td class='TTRow_right'>2,17,06,54,147</td>
                                        <td class='TTRow_right'>1,32,95,642</td>
                                        <td class='TTRow_right'>2,18,39,49,789</td>
                                        <td class='TTRow_right'>100.00</td>
                                        <td class='TTRow_right'>2,17,99,49,744</td>
                                    </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib
import re
s = soup(str(urllib.urlopen('https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/shpSecurities.aspx?scripcd=500209&qtrid=96.00').read()), 'lxml')
results = filter(None, [re.sub('[\n\r]+|\s{2,}', '', i.text) for i in s.find_all('td', {'class':re.compile('TTRow_right|TTRow_left')})])
```

Output:

```
[u'(A) Promoter & Promoter Group', u'19', u'28,17,02,889', u'28,17,02,889', u'12.90', u'28,17,02,889', u'(B) Public', u'9,16,058', u'1,87,81,45,362', u'1,32,95,642', u'1,89,14,41,004', u'86.61', u'1,88,74,40,959', u'(C1) Shares underlying DRs', u'0.00', u'(C2) Shares held by Employee Trust', u'1', u'1,08,05,896', u'1,08,05,896', u'0.49', u'1,08,05,896', u'(C) Non Promoter-Non Public', u'1', u'1,08,05,896', u'1,08,05,896', u'0.49', u'1,08,05,896', u'Grand Total', u'9,16,078', u'2,17,06,54,147', u'1,32,95,642', u'2,18,39,49,789', u'100.00', u'2,17,99,49,744']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was looking for this.Now I can work on this output to divide them into different rows..